# Should I remove all the event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

Most of the time, I don't remove the event handler when there is only one or two of them.
But now I am designing a webpage that will use ajax to fetch HTML content to append into the DOM.

```
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><span id="mainMenuAcc">profile</span></li>
        <li><span id="mainMenuTop">contact</span></li>
    </ul>
    sdfgsegg <br/>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body> 


$.ajax({
    url:url,
    beforeSend: function(){
        showSpinner(true);
    },
    success: function(result){
        container.html(result);
        if (page1){
            page1_initUI();
        } else if (page2){
            page2_initUI();
        }
    },
    error: function(obj, errMsj){
        alert("Ajax connection fail. " + errMsj);
    },
    complete: function(){
        
        showSpinner(false);
    }
                    
  });
```

As you can see, user can click on the different list items to switch the pages, and so the DOM object will be inserted and removed repeatedly. `page1_initUI` and `page2_initUI` will run event handler binding after ajax call succeed.

I worry that this will cause some memory leak or drawback in this case. Can anyone advise me how should I do in this scenario? Will our browser garbage-collect the event handler automatically?

Comment: Where are the event handlers? You might consider using delegated event handlers so that you can just set them once on document ready and they'll continue to work after each Ajax load.

Comment: <<As you can see>> No, we cannot see it...  If an element is removed from DOM, associated handlers are removed too except if you use some kind of delegation

Comment: Start worrying if you have some performance issues. In that case check your page in Chrome developer tools Timeline tab.